# Show Progress bar with limit and completed values in jQuery Ui

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, progress-bar, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a requirement to show progressed value and remaining value in Progress Bar.

Here is my html content.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <style>
 .bar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .list {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }

  .items .ui-selected {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .items {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .items li {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .weekday {
    float: left;
  }

  .availablelist {
    background-color: orange;
    display: inline;
  }
   </style>
   </head>

  <body>
   <div style="float:left;width:500px;">
   <div><h2>Total Credits = <span id="total-credits">80</span></h2> </div>
 </div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br>
<div id="timetable" style="float:left;width:700px;">    
  <div class="weekday">
     <ul class="items">
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Jhonny</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="15" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Tim</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
       <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">George</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="25" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
       <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Melissa</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="20" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Alice</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="5" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="weekday">
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Jhonny</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="20" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Tim</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">George</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Melissa</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
        <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Alice</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>

 <div id = "progressbar"></div>
 </div>
 <script>
$(function () {
    $("#timetable .items").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul"   
    });        

    /* for progress bar */ 
    var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" );
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
       value: 0,
       max:300
    });

    function progress() {
       var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;
       progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );
       if ( val <= 00 ) {
          setTimeout( progress, 100 );
       }
    }
    setTimeout(progress, 3000);
    /* for progress bar */ 
});
```

I have a hidden value for each li items with some credits, so Whenever any li is dragged from right and dropped to left side, I need to sum the value of each left hand side li credits and match with the Total credits and show the Progress bar with values like below Image

[image]

Also I need to ensure drag should not allow if credit limit is crossed to 80,

How this can be done?

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?  You have a progress bar.  You can set the max value.  You can change the value.  So no problem with the progress bar *despite the question title*.  Is the problem creating two lists that can have values dragged between them?  The jquery-ui site has a working example of this.  Is the problem getting values from the selection list?  `$("ul.selected li")` will give you that.  Put another way, what have you tried to solve your requirement?  (not just create a progress bar, that doesn't solve the requirement)

Comment: @freedomn-m, I am looking for suggestions, I have no idea about progress bar, how the above functionality can be implemented?

Comment: "*I have no idea about progress bar*" - that's ok, you can find how to draw/update a progress bar, **by looking at the code in your own question**

Comment: @freedomn-m,do you suggest me any answer?

Comment: Hi @Manjunath i am trying to understand how the the events are supposed to happen here. From what i can see you have 2 lists, and if i understand correctly when items are moved between lists this affects the progress bar. If possible can you explain this in a bit more detail, so then i can help, just do it step by step.

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham, What i am trying to do here is, I need to show the progress bar with sum of the left hand side credits with the Total credits on page load. Whenever user tried to drag from right to left, I need to check sum of the left hand side credits are greater than the total credits or not, if the selected item for dragging is not crossing the total credit, then need to allow it to drop otherwise need to prevent dragging. Once drop is allowed then i need to sum that item credit with previous one and show it in progress bar, Are you clear now?

Comment: @Manjunath so you have current set the values on the left to 75 and the total you have typed in is 80, so getting the values on load is simple enough, you need to tap into the change events on your sortable object. I need a little more information but i think i should be able to do this. Can you potentially provide an example scenario, so i know what outcome to expect?

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham, No I searched for an example, Didn't find anywhere so posted this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery .sortable has a property called update. It is an event that first when elements move from list to another. You can add your logic there.

See this example:

```js
$(function() {

  let progressbar = $("#progressbar");
  let fill = progressbar.find(".fill");
  let incomplete = progressbar.find(".incomplete");

  $(".items.first-col").sortable({
    connectWith: ".items.second-col",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      recalculate(ui.item.closest(".items"));
    }
  });

  $(".items.second-col").sortable({
    connectWith: ".items.first-col",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      recalculate(ui.sender);
    }
  });


  // Calculate items
  function recalculate(items) {
    let total = 0;

    items.find(".credits").each(function() {
      total += parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
    });

    // dont go over 80
    if (total <= 80) {
      let percentage = total * 80 / 100;
      fill.width(percentage + "%");
      fill.find("span").text(total);
      incomplete.find("span").text(80 - total);
    } else {
      $("#timetable .items").sortable('cancel');
    }

    progressbar.attr("data-full", "false");
    if (total == 80) {
      progressbar.attr("data-full", "true");
      fill.width("100%");
    }
  }
  recalculate(jQuery(".items.first-col"));
  $(".items.first-col").sortable("refresh");

});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.list {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.items .ui-selected {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.items {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.items li {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.weekday {
  float: left;
}

.availablelist {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline;
}

#progressbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#progressbar[data-full='true'] .incomplete {
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
}

#progressbar>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#progressbar .fill {
  background-color: #009a9b;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#progressbar span {
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div style="float:left;width:500px;">
  <div>
    <h2>Total Credits = <span id="total-credits">80</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br>
<div id="timetable" style="float:left;width:700px;">
  <div class="weekday">
    <ul class="items first-col">
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Jhonny</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="15" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Tim</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">George</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="25" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Melissa</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="20" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Alice</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="5" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="weekday">
    <ul class="items second-col">
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Jhonny</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="20" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Tim</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">George</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Melissa</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb">Alice</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="10" name="credits" class="credits">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div id="progressbar" data-full='false'>
    <div class='fill'>
      Total: <span>60</span> / 80 credits
    </div>
    <div class='incomplete'>
      Incomplete: <span>20</span>credits
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a version with data-* attribute instead of hidden values:

```js
$(function() {

  let progressbar = $("#progressbar");
  let fill = progressbar.find(".fill");
  let incomplete = progressbar.find(".incomplete");

  $(".items.first-col").sortable({
    connectWith: ".items.second-col",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      recalculate(ui.item.closest(".items"));
    }
  });

  $(".items.second-col").sortable({
    connectWith: ".items.first-col",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      recalculate(ui.sender);
    }
  });


  // Calculate items
  function recalculate(items) {
    let total = 0;

    items.find("label").each(function() {
      total += parseInt(jQuery(this).attr("data-value"));
    });

    // dont go over 80
    if (total <= 80) {
      let percentage = total * 80 / 100;
      fill.width(percentage + "%");
      fill.find("span").text(total);
      incomplete.find("span").text(80 - total);
    } else {
      $("#timetable .items").sortable('cancel');
    }

    progressbar.attr("data-full", "false");
    if (total == 80) {
      progressbar.attr("data-full", "true");
      fill.width("100%");
    }
  }

  $(".items.first-col").sortable("refresh");

});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.list {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.items .ui-selected {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.items {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.items li {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.weekday {
  float: left;
}

.availablelist {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline;
}

#progressbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#progressbar[data-full='true'] .incomplete {
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
}

#progressbar>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#progressbar .fill {
  background-color: #009a9b;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#progressbar span {
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div style="float:left;width:500px;">
  <div>
    <h2>Total Credits = <span id="total-credits">80</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br>
<div id="timetable" style="float:left;width:700px;">
  <div class="weekday">
    <ul class="items first-col">
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value="15">Jhonny</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='10'>Tim</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='25'>George</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='20'>Melissa</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='5'>Alice</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="weekday">
    <ul class="items second-col">
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='20'>Jhonny</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='10'>Tim</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='10'>George</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='10'>Melissa</label>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <label class="core-ins-tag-numb" data-value='10'>Alice</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div id="progressbar" data-full='false'>
    <div class='fill'>
      Total: <span>60</span> / 80 credits
    </div>
    <div class='incomplete'>
      Incomplete: <span>20</span>credits
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Kalimah, Thanks for the answer, But this is not my requirement, I think you are not clear with my question.

Comment: @Manjunath I updated the code. You can check it now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks this is almost working but one small issue, I don't want to show Incomplete 0 credit, Once it is fulfill with the total credits, progress bar should be 100% with green with no white space left on the right side

Comment: Also, once i reached to Total i,e 80 in above example, I'm unable to drag from left to right, The dragged items from right to left can we reverted, that is not happening

Comment: hi @Kalimah, u got me, can you update me that changes pls?

Comment: @Manjunath I updated the code. I also added a version with data-* attribute instead of using hidden input which uses less HTML.

Comment: Is it working now? for me its not working now @kalimah

Comment: @Manjunath It is working fine for me. Maybe post a screenshot or screencast of how it looks on your side.

Comment: I have used the updated code-sinppet as it is, right now I am unable to drag from right to left, and total value is 60 even if crosses 80, screenshot here https://paste.pics/7CRGC

Comment: I think the main issue was `recalculate` did not run on load. Please check again now.

Answer (score 0):

This link solves your problem:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Animated-Step-Progress-Indicator-With-jQuery-StepProgressBar.html

```html
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Step-Progress-Indicator-With-jQuery-StepProgressBar/src/jquery.stepProgressBar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<h1>jQuery StepProgressBar Plugin Example</h1>
<div id="myGoal"></div>
<span class="btn btn-primary" id="get-current-value-btn">get current value</span><br>
        <span class="btn btn-primary" id="set-current-value-btn">set current value to 500</span><br>
        <span class="btn btn-primary" id="find-step-btn">find step with value = 500 (see in console)</span><br>
        <span class="btn btn-primary" id="add-step-btn">add step with value = 250</span><br>
        <span class="btn btn-primary" id="remove-step-btn">remove step with value = 500</span>
        </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Step-Progress-Indicator-With-jQuery-StepProgressBar/src/jquery.stepProgressBar.js"></script>
<script>
$('#myGoal').stepProgressBar({
  currentValue: 200,
  steps: [
    { value: 100 },
    {
      topLabel: '500 custom unit',
      value: 500,
      bottomLabel: '<i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>'
    },
    {
      value: 800,
      bottomLabel: '<i class="material-icons">card_giftcard</i>'
    },
    {  
      value: 1000, 
      bottomLabel: '<i class="material-icons">star</i>',
      mouseOver: function() { alert('mouseOver'); },
      click: function() { alert('click'); }
    }
  ],
  unit: '$'
});

        $('#get-current-value-btn').click(function() {
          alert($('#myGoal').stepProgressBar('getCurrentValue'));
        });
        $('#set-current-value-btn').click(function() {
          $('#myGoal').stepProgressBar('setCurrentValue', 500);
        });
        $('#find-step-btn').click(function() {
          console.log($('#myGoal').stepProgressBar('findStep', 500));
        });
        $('#add-step-btn').click(function() {
          $('#myGoal').stepProgressBar('addStep', {value: 250});
        });
        $('#remove-step-btn').click(function() {
          $('#myGoal').stepProgressBar('removeStep', 500);
        });
</script>
```